# Swift sprite kit activity indicator

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to add a simple, built in activity indicator to my sprite kit game as follows:

```
let activityInd = UIActivityIndicatorView()
activityInd.center = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2)
self.scene!.view?.addSubview(activityInd)
```

But it does not appear on the screen. Anyone knows a work around?

Comment: What is `self` in this situation?

Comment: Have you called startAnimating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
let activityInd = UIActivityIndicatorView()
activityInd.center = CGPointMake(view.bounds.midX, view.bounds.midY)
activityInd.startAnimating()
scene!.view?.addSubview(activityInd)
```